# I got NotFoundHttpException when I write unit test for an API in 2 functions

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm working on Laravel 5.4 and trying to write the unit test to cover my function.
But I got a crazy bug. Please have look at my code and help me.

Here is my test file

```
class UserControllerTest extends TestCase
{

    use DatabaseTransactions;

    protected $isCreateToken = true;


    public function testViewAccountDetailWithFieldsOK()
    {
        $this->get('/v1.0/me');
        $this->assertResponseStatus(200);
    }

    public function testViewAccountDetailOK()
    {
        $this->get('/v1.0/me');
        $this->assertResponseStatus(200);
    }
}
```

When I try to run command: `phpunit`
I got this error:

```
PHPUnit 5.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.F                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 710 ms, Memory: 14.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Controller\Api\UserControllerTest::testViewAccountDetailOK
Expected status code 200, got 404.
Failed asserting that 404 matches expected 200.

/Users/johnnguyen/Workspace/Laravel/mobile/vendor/laravel/browser-kit-testing/src/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php:744
/Users/johnnguyen/Workspace/Laravel/mobile/tests/Controller/Api/UserControllerTest.php:24
/Users/johnnguyen/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:186
/Users/johnnguyen/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:116
```

But when I run separately for each function:

```
John-Nguyen:mobile johnnguyen$ phpunit --filter=testViewAccountDetailOK
PHPUnit 5.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 591 ms, Memory: 14.00MB

OK (1 test, 2 assertions)
```

2 functions are the same code.
but I got the issue `404: NotFoundHttpException`
This is the first time I got this issue.

Can anyone help me for this bug?

Many thanks.

Comment: If running the tests individually works, but running them consecutively does not, then you've done something in the first test that affects the second. This indicates that you are not properly setting up your tests to be completely independent of one another.

Comment: I found my issue, it's issue from routes. I used `require_once` and it made that issue. after that, I changed it to `require` and everything is ok.

Comment: Glad you got it working, but that can't possibly be the problem. *require* includes a file. *require_once* includes a file only if it has not yet been included. Repeatedly including a file that's already included may solve the problem in the short term, but it still means you're not setting your tests up properly. Each test should be a fully independent black box *not* dependent on previous (or other) tests. Consider using setUpBeforeClass() to do your includes.